# Adverse effects of meta data file deletion

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

We're using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0.5 to synchronize files between one server and multiple hosts. We've noticed that when the connection is interrupted and then reconnects it starts trying to sync again. This is good. However, it can no longer sync--it's like it is blocked. When we delete the sync meta data file in the folder that it is trying to sync to, everything starts syncing again just fine. The simplest solution I can think of is to have the code check for the presence of the meta data file and delete it before starting sync. What are the downsides of this approach and is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the metadata stores what has been synched. if you delete it, you will always initiate a full sync, not an incremental sync. as a practice, backup the metadata file before you sync and in case of cancelled syncs, restore the metadata file. you may want to store the metadata file in a folder separate from the files you're synching.